# Stack Overflow is down

Tags: bug

Stack Overflow is currently down, at least so it seems.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be back online

Comment: We're aware of the issue and yanking the affected web servers right now

Comment: I posted at the same time, mine got marked as a dupe lol

Comment: Malware attack?

Comment: O nein, Mein Leben!

Comment: Ara ara... seems that SO IIS settings misconfigured. Let the quick response team starts working.

Comment: Not only SO, most of the [SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309427/312043)

Comment: @mplungjan no malware attack, just a web server being put into rotation when it shouldn't have been

Comment: did you or did you not order the code red ?!?

Comment: How can you post on the meta if there is no main site... :thinking:

Comment: @L_Church How can you post on Twitter when Facebook is down? ;)

Comment: strongly related: **[What's the quickest way to tell if most of the people on Earth have disappeared?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/110353/21198)**

Comment: And we have word from [Nick Craver](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/989141900174266369)

Comment: @gnat [Better yet, post an off-topic question and see how long it takes for it to be put on hold](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110316/whats-the-quickest-way-to-tell-if-most-of-the-people-on-earth-have-disappeared/110353#comment336231_110353)

Answer (score 20):

We are in the process of upgrading our web servers. During the rebuild of a server it went back into rotation before we were ready for it to go back. This resulted in the "Default Web Site" that comes with an IIS install to appear. HAProxy regarded the page as a valid response and put it back in rotation.

Comment: Was this the only issue? I saw reports of IIS's Server Error page (which shouldn't be shown when a website is in production mode) and reports of 404s with the HTTP Response Reason set to "Server Error" (that reason should be a 500).

Comment: @Poke Same issue. IIS loaded the default site. You'd get that if you went to the index page, but the default IIS 404 for any other page, since the default site doesn't have any pages to load

Comment: @Machavity I understand that a 404 is expected in that case. What was unexpected was the reason associated with the 404. The [HTTP 1.1 RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4) shows that the expected reason for a 404 is "Not Found". While the reason phrases are only recommendations "Server Error" is the exact recommendation for a 500 and not a 404.

Comment: @Poke But 500 doesn't apply here. 500 means the server had some sort of error. As far as IIS was concerned, it was working properly

Comment: @Machavity I agree with you. That's why I'm asking about it. The discrepancy between the response code and the response reason looks like a bug.

Comment: Our load balancer (haproxy) checks the root (index) for a 200 response code, which the default site returned, so the LB did not view the server as in error.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the reports I saw in chat. It may just be the title of the 404 page and not the http response reason that said "Server Error". https://i.stack.imgur.com/J06mQ.gif

Comment: Why don't you just admit you forgot to feed the hamsters.

Comment: In the recent past, SE team [used to announce such things in advance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307744/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-march-17-2018-at-1300-utc-9am-us-eastern), letting users know when the sites will be down. Why not in this case?

Comment: @ShadowWizard they did not know that they were going to screw up in advance:)

Comment: @Martin any upgrade has risk of failing, especially upgrading web servers.